# Can Flaming sphere be moved twice in a turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, movement, actions

[Flaming Sphere](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flaming-sphere)

> It moves 30 feet per round
>
> The sphere moves as long as you actively direct it (a move action for you)

So if I spend both my standard and move actions, can I double move a sphere that has not entered a square with another creature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're only moving it a maximum of 15ft each time, and not hitting the same square twice, I don't see why not. Like it says, 30ft/rd is the max here, and you get two chances to move it.

Comment: But there's no point... "If it enters a space with a creature, it stops moving for the round"

Answer (score 5):

No because "It moves 30 feet per round" no matter how many times you tell it where to go.

Comment: Terse, but accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The spell description doesn't specify, but you would think yes, as long as you moved it less than a total of 30 feet, or didn't hit anyone. BUT... the description says:
"The sphere moves as long as you actively direct it (a move action for you); otherwise..."
You can only move it up to 2 times, but moving it twice takes your entire turn. Also, if you're staggered, just cast the sphere, moved, or taken any action but a free/swift/immediate action, you can only move it 1 (or less) time.